# MATLAB implementation of MLE for Logistic Regression

Tags: self-study, logistic, generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, matlab

The following is an **assignment**.

The matrix $\mathbf{x}$ containing the external factors has dimension $4\times1000$, and the vector $\mathbf{y}$ containing the categorical variable has dimension $1\times1000$.

I have to fit a GLM model of the type

$$ \pi(t) = \frac{1}{1 + exp{\left(\beta_0 + \sum_{l=1}^m \beta_l u_t^l\right)}}, $$

where $u_t^l$ is the $l$th external factor at time $t$.

The likelihood function I came up with is the following:

$$ L(\beta) = -\sum_{i=1}^N \left[ y_i  \log \left( \frac{1}{1+\exp(-\beta^T\mathbf{x}_i)} \right) +\\ (1-y_i)\log \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+\exp(-\beta^T\mathbf{x}_i)} \right) \right] .$$

In order to maximize it, I computed the gradient:

$$ \nabla_{\beta} L = \sum_{i=1}^N \left( y_i - \frac{1}{1+\exp(-\beta^T\mathbf{x}_i)} \right)\mathbf{x}_i ,$$

and the updating expression is:

$$ \beta = \beta + \nabla_{\beta} L .$$

I want to implement it in MATLAB and for doing so I would like to first transform this last expression in matrix form:

$$ \beta = \beta + \left( \mathbf{y} - \frac{1}{1+\exp(-\beta^T\mathbf{x})} \right)\mathbf{x} .$$

I've been trying for hours now but the result is not correct (too many $1$s or $0$s according to the initial values).

Here's the question: can somebody explain what the dimensions of the different elements for the matrix form should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be pretty straightforward to code:

```
function llik = fun(b, X, Y)  
num = X * b;  
prb = exp(num .* Y) ./ (1 + exp(num));  
llik = -sum(log(prb));  
end
```

Where:
(Y) is a column vector (say 1000 x 1)
(X) is a matrix of predictors (say 1000 x 5)
Key is exp(num .* Y) that will be used to obtain both proba(Y==1) and proba(Y==0)

Given the relative simplicity of this model and the efficiency of Matlab optimisation routines (fmincon/fminunc), I don't think you need to code the gradient, but can easily be done if really needed.

This model has a closed-form solution and then the results should in principle not depend on the choice of starting values. Hope this helps.

=== SCRIPT TO ESTIMATE THE MODEL ===
Here I assume that you first have created a script including the log-likelihood function only - Let's say this script is called "LOGISTIC_LL".

```
% IMPORT DATA
A = importdata('path.csv')

% DATA SPECIFICATION
Y = A.data(:,1);
X = A.data(:,2:end);

% VARIABLE NAMES
Vnames = {'x1','x2',etc.};

% STARTING VALUES
b = zeros(length(Vnames),1);

% OPTIMISATION
options = optimoptions(@fminunc,'Display','iter','MaxIterations',1e3,'MaxFunctionEvaluations',1e5);
tic;
[paramhat,fval,~,~,grad,hessian] = fminunc(@(b)LOGISTIC_LL(b, X, Y), b, options);
```

Finally, you could create another function to reshape results and compute other statistics (SEs, Pval, etc).

Comment: Forgot to say that (b) corresponds to the vector of model parameters

Comment: I tried to use *fminsearch* for the likelihood function but I had the same problems. I actually do not understand what you are doing here. Is this the function to be passed to an optimization routines?

Comment: Yes. I usually create a first script in which I write my objective function (say log-likelihood for a logistic regression) and then I create another file in which I estimate the model - For instance in this last file I would import the data, declare the different objects (Y, X, etc.) and run the other script.

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly (see "SCRIPT TO ESTIMATE THE MODEL")

Comment: Thanks. But the result I get is exactly the same as the one I get with *my* approach. Maybe I did not understand Logistic Regression well enough but I expected to see the same *distribution* of $0$s and $1$s as in $Y$. Here, instead, I also have a lot of values in-between. To see this, I simply use the expression for $\pi$ I wrote above with *paramhat*.

Comment: This is because what you model in a logistic regression is proba(Y==1) - This is why you obtain values between 0 and 1. If you really want something in (0/1) you could transform your predicted proba into predicted outcomes (e.g., if P(Y==1) > 0.5 then predicted outcome = 1 and otherwise) - Finally you can compare the predicted outcomes with the actual (observed) ones and compute a measure of agreement (% of correctly predicted events) - This will tell you something about model performance